# react-native-google-fit package can't be authorized

Tags: react-native, google-fit, google-fit-sdk

I am trying to get GoogleFit working on my android device and after i followed steps from https://developers.google.com/fit/android/get-api-key when i try to call GoogleFit.authorize() method all i get is :

```
{
  "message": "Authorization cancelled",
  "success": false,
}
```

I cannot resolve what am i doing wrong.I generated client_secrets.json file from GC for a RN project i have built but still i cannot get any response when i try calling this API.

Anyone had this issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem some days ago.
For me, the problem was related to the SHA-1 that I put into the Google Console.

I considered the wrong `debug.keystore` file, while running the following command:

```sh
keytool -list -v -keystore ./debug.keystore -alias androiddebugkey -storepass android -keypass android
```

If you're running your app into an emulator, you must use the local `debug.keystore` file (into `<myApp>/android/app/debug.keystore`), instead of the `~/.android/debug.keystore`. Hope it helps